# Installed Android on Mac, cannot find SDK

Tags: eclipse, android, macos, installation

Using Mac OS X 10.6.2, Eclipse SDK 3.5.2.
I installed the Android plugin, following the instructions at:
http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html

In the next section (step #3) it says:
For the SDK Location in the main panel, click Browse... and locate your downloaded SDK directory.

I cannot find such a directory. When I try some other directory, it says the directory has no 'tools' folder, so I've searched for a 'tools' folder, but none of those found (of 15 or 20) appear to be Android.

Where is this directory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to also down load the Android SDK, and you can put it anywhere you wish..

The android SDK can be found at the following link http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Answer (score 2):

Usually you can find sdk like this : `/users/user/Library/Android/sdk`

If you can't find Library directory, then it might be in hidden state. To make it visible, use below command in terminal.

```
chflags nohidden ~/Library/
```

Comment: This helped me, could not find this folder for the life of me. Note this is where Android Studio usually puts it by default

Answer (score 1):

I seem to have missed the line that says to *first* download the SDK separately!
Sorry for the "noise" on this list.

Comment: This should best be posted as a comment on the accepted answer, David. BTW, your "noise" helped me today.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you can find sdk like this : `/users/<username>/Library/Android/sdk`

`/users/<username>/Library` may be hidden.

Open view options by :

View -> Show View Options **or** <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>

Tick on Show Library Folder.